# Remove last dot in title numbering

Tags: formatting, chapters, koma-script, punctuation, appendices

My current document is processed like this:

```
1. Some chapter
1.1. Some section
1.1.1. Some subsection

Appendix A.
Some appendix
```

What I want to have:

```
1 Some chapter
1.1 Some section
1.1.1 Some subsection

Appendix A: Some appendix
```

So I want the last dots of the numbering removed for the main part. For the appendix, I want a colon instead of the dot and the title in the same line.

A small example, including all packages used:

```
\documentclass[appendixprefix=true,11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
%The packages used in my document
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
%Appendix definition (Write "Appendix A")
\makeatletter
\newcommand\appendix@numberline[1]{\appendixname\ #1: }
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{
    \let\protect\numberline\protect\appendix@numberline}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\appendix
\chapter{Last chapter}
\end{document}
```

How can I make the colon and the title in the same line. And how do I remove the last dots of the titles?

---

Symbol1's answer doesn't work. Error message:

```
Undefined control sequence. \@makechapterhead ...mdepth >\m@ne \if@mainmatter
\huge \bfseries \@chapapp ... l.108 \chapter{Definition of the Problem}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how `\autodot` works, but `\def\autodot{}` solves part of the question.

Comment: Yes, it does. Now I only need the Appendix title in the same line as the "Appendix A".

Comment: `numbers=noenddot` removes the dots in a simpler way, btw

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's how you can obtain the output you're after in the [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes:

[image]

```
\documentclass[appendixprefix=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{%
  \patchcmd{\@@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
    {\endgraf\nobreak\vskip.5\baselineskip}% <search>
    {\hspace*{-.5em}:\space}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
  \patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
    {\addchaptertocentry{\thechapter}}% <search>
    {\addchaptertocentry{Appendix~\thechapter:}}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\patchcmd{\protect\l@chapter}% <cmd>
      {1.5em}% <search>
      {6.5em}% <replace>
      {}{}}% <success><failure>
}
\renewcommand{\autodot}{}% Remove all end-of-counter dots
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}

\appendix
\chapter{Last chapter}

\end{document}
```

The dots are removed through a redefinition of `\autodot`, while the Appendix formatting is done via a `\patchcmd` of `\@@makechapterhead` when you call `\appendix`. The final patch adjusts the width of the `\numberline` box from `1.5em` to `6.5em`. This adjustment is specific to the chapter-related entry in the ToC as it deals with `\l@chapter`.

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides the patching capability.

Comment: Nice! This works fine. But is it possible to also write the "Appendix A:" into the TOC?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have the colon in the TOC also, which isn't given in your updated anwser btw.

Comment: Never mind, I found out where to add the colon: `{Appendix~\thechapter:}`

Comment: @the_Seppi: I've added it to my answer.

Comment: This no longer works with an uptodate KOMA-Script version.

Answer (score 5):

Since KOMA-Script version 3.20 you can use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`. So here is a new suggestion:

```
\documentclass[
  %appendixprefix=true,%<- removed
  11pt,a4paper,
  numbers=noenddot% <- added
]{scrreprt}[2016/05/10]% needs at least version 3.20

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=\chaptertocdepth,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=2.3em,
  dynnumwidth,
  linefill=\hfill,
  entryformat=\appendixtocformat,
  entrynumberformat=\appendixtocnumberformat,
  pagenumberformat=\appendixtocpagenumberformat
]{tocline}{appendixchapter}
\newcommand*\appendixtocformat[1]{{\usekomafont{chapterentry}#1}}
\newcommand*\appendixtocnumberformat[1]{{\def\autodot{:}\appendixname\ #1}}
\newcommand*\appendixtocpagenumberformat[1]
  {{\usekomafont{chapterentry}\usekomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}#1}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\appendix
  {%
    \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
      \mbox{\appendixname{\nobreakspace}\thechapter:%
        \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\appendixname\ \thechapter:\enskip}%
    \xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}
      {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}
      {\addtocentrydefault{appendixchapter}{#1}{#2}}%
      {}{\PatchFailed}%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\appendix
\chapter{Last chapter}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: ```numbers=noenddot``` was sufficient for me to get rid of them +1

Answer (score 2):

Here you are

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\vspace*{50\p@}{\parindent\z@\raggedright\normalfont\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne\if@mainmatter\huge\bfseries\@chapapp\space\thechapter: \fi\fi\interlinepenalty\@M\Huge\bfseries#1\par\nobreak\vskip40\p@}}
\makeatother
\chapter{CHAPI}
\section{SECI}
\subsection{SUBSECTI}
\appendix
\chapter{CHAPII}
\section{SECII}
\subsection{SUBSECTII}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Error: `Undefined control sequence.
\@makechapterhead ...mdepth >\m@ne \if@mainmatter 
                                                  \huge \bfseries \@chapapp ...
l.108 \chapter{Definition of the Problem}` Definition of the problem is the 1st numbered chapter

Comment: @the_Seppi The line 108 isn't in the example here. You have tried another code. The code here works.

Comment: This is because of the document class. Here, `book` is used. However, I'm using `scrreprt`, in which the error occurs, if you change it here. Besides, this refers to line 108 of the .toc file

Answer (score 2):

The following is almost the same as @werners answer, with a slight difference. With the option `appendixprefix` you get the prefix *appendix* just before the number. This contradicts with having the title on the same line (this is the way it is implemented). The main idea is the same, patching `\@@makechapterhead` as there happens the magic. At first i saved just nothing to be printed as autodot. When the appendix starts, some redefinitions are made, for example
- restoring the autodot to print a colon (`:`)
- patching the linebreak to simply nothing (no need to fiddle with spaces, the default KOMA is in control)
- If you want only the chapter entries indented by the needed amount, it gets indented dynamically by the contents of `\appendixTocString`. If you decide at a later point, not to print the word *Appendix*, remove it frome the string and it will be properly indented.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[
appendixprefix=true,
]{scrreprt}
%The packages used in my document
%\usepackage{scrhack}%patches listings
%\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\autodot}{}%
\newcommand{\appendixTocString}{\appendixname\space\thechapter\autodot}%
\newlength{\appendixTocStringLength}%
\settowidth{\appendixTocStringLength}{\appendixTocString}%
\addtolength{\appendixTocStringLength}{1.5em}%
\makeatletter%
\gappto{\appendix}{%Doing everything in the appendix%
\patchcmd{\@@makechapterhead}{\endgraf\nobreak\vskip.5\baselineskip}{}{}{}%
\renewcommand{\autodot}{:}%
\addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\patchcmd{\protect\l@chapter}%
    {1.5em}%
    {\protect\appendixTocStringLength}%
    {}{}}%
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addchaptertocentry{\thechapter}{\scr@ds@tocentry}%
}{%
\addchaptertocentry{\appendixTocString}{\scr@ds@tocentry}}{}{}%
}%
\makeatother%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\appendix
\chapter{In case the chapter title is really long, we need to
make sure that it gets indented properly.}
\section{appendix section}
\subsection{appendix subsection}
\chapter{appendix chapter}
\section{appendix section}
\subsection{appendix subsection}
\chapter{appendix chapter}
\section{appendix section}
\subsection{appendix subsection}
\chapter{appendix chapter}
\section{appendix section}
\subsection{appendix subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To be honest, i find the output highly quesionable and incosistent. If you want the autodot in the toc as well, remove the commentsign and merge the lines (removing the space).

Comment: Did this, it added the colon in the TOC. But how do I remove the indentation of the non-appendix chapters and their subs in the TOC? I don't want them indented, only the appendix TOC entries.

Comment: @the_Seppi I changed the example to dynamically adjust the indentation dependant of the string you want to print.